# RSpec - @controller is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I've got a very basic RoR website and need to start writing some RSpec tests for it. I have an 'about' page that doesn't require a logged-in user, and is controlled by my PagesController. The about page works great when run from a browser. I am trying to simply trying to test that, kind of like in the RoR Tutorial.

I'm using Rails 3, RSpec 2.7.0, Windows

pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def about
    end
end
```

pages_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "PagesController" do
    describe "GET 'about'" do
        render_views
        it "should be successful" do
            get 'about'
            response.should be_success
        end
    end
end
```

For what it's worth, here's my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

But when I run the test, I get:

```
Failures:

1) PagesController GET 'about' should be successful
  Failure/Error: get 'about'
   RuntimeError:
     @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any help appreciated. I know this has to be an easy one! Thanks!!
Jacob

Comment: not sure here: don't you have to 'new' a controller instance?

Answer (score 42):

Try to change

```
describe "PagesController" do
```

to

```
describe PagesController do
```

Comment: I found no difference using quoted name or real class name. As long as HTTP request was present (i.e. get), after which the controller ivar and method successfully return.

Comment: I was getting this error even though I was already describing the class, not the class _name._ In my case it was caused by a lower-level `context :a_symbol` instead of `context 'a string'`.